# How to Handle dynamic meta tags in angular for server side rendering (ssr)?

Tags: node.js, angular, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to render dynamic data in title, meta, descriptions tags data in angular application using nguniversal package but I'm not finding proper documents how to use it. Can anyone help me in this?

Iam trying to follow https://www.positronx.io/angular-seo-set-dynamic-page-title-meta-tags-in-universal-app/ this doc but it is not much clear to find solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What backend stack are you using? How are you serving the app?

Answer (score 0):

u need to inject Meta and Title into your component/service/resolver and then just use:
`this.meta.addTag({name: key, content: value})`
Full example:

```
import { Meta, Title} from '@angular/platform-browser';

...

 constructor(private meta: Meta,
             public title: Title) {
 this.initMetaForMyPage()
  }

 private initMetaForMyPage() {
  this.meta.addTag({name: 'description', content: 'my custom description'});
  /*... any other meta tags that u need to set */
  this.title.setTitle('my current page title');
 }
```

I recommend setting all meta in your resolvers, after receiving data from API.